# Can tcpdump capture received UDP packets with checksum errors?

Tags: udp, checksum, tcpdump

I tried using the following command to capture udp packets with incorrect checksum, 10.192.132.66 is local ip, but nothing is get, why?

tcpdump -ni any -vvv udp and dst host 10.192.132.66 |  grep 'bad udp cksum'

but the following command can capture tcp packets with incorrect checksum.

tcpdump -ni any -vvv tcp and dst host 10.192.132.66 |  grep 'incorrect'

Comment: Works for me. No idea what is different for you. Note that you better make stdout of tcpdump line buffered (option `-l`), so that the output lines get filtered immediately